# Adding Data To An Array Using PHP

Tags: php

If I have large set of data in an array from like this,

1 => A
2 => B
.... etc

How can I add a set of data to the end of the array using PHP? For example if there are 26 elements

26 => Z

How can I add 27 =>AA at the end of the array using PHP? We can get the number of elements using count, but because the large amount of data can't use arrary_push to add the new data at the end. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: When you say large amount of data, how many elements are you talking about? A-Z is only 26, and adding AA means 27... that's nnot large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quite simple:

```
$myArray = array('A','B', 'C');

$myArray[] = 'D';
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of PHP's Perl-style character incrementor

```
$data = range('A','Z');
$last = end($data);
$last++;
$data[] = $last;

var_dump($data);
```